Use Spring OAuth2 with Angular Dev Server
I created a simple Spring Boot (3.2.4) OAuth2 Server with Spring Security 6.1.5 OpenID Connect 1.0 runnung on Port 9000
OAuth2 Server on Port 9000
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults()); // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain standardSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()).formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient loginClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
           .clientId("login-client")
           .clientSecret("{noop}openid-connect")
           .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
           .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
           .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
           .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/login-client")
           .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
           .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
           .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
           .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
           .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(loginClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

}

The OAuth2 Spring Boot client is running on Port 8080
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()).oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}

With configuration file
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          login-client:
            provider: spring
            client-id: login-client
            client-secret: openid-connect
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/login-client
            scope: openid
            client-name: spring
        provider:
          spring:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token
            jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/jwks

And a simple secured ressource
@RestController
public class OAuth2UserController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public OAuth2User user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User oauth2User) {
        return oauth2User;
    }

}

When I deploy a production build of my angular application with the Spring Boot OAuth Client in the target/classes/static folder, everything is working as expected. When I open the application in a browser http://localhost:8080/ I get redirected to the Oauth2 Server and to the login page on the CLient, where I can give username and password. Then I get redirected with a JSESSION-ID Cookie to the angular application and have access to the secured ressources.
My problem is, that I can't manage to do a OAuth2 Login with the angular dev server.
When I start my angular application in dev-mode with ng serve, the angular application is loaded on the dev server, so I already have access, but when I try to access a secured resource, I can't manage the redirect and the OAuth2 Login. I tried with { observe: 'response' }:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, HttpClientModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'oauth-ng';
  userInfo$: Observable<any> | undefined;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userInfo$ = this.httpClient.get<string>('user', { observe: 'response' });
  }

}

I tried to get it working with a proxy.config.json
var proxyConfig = [
  {
    context: ["/user"],
    target: "http://localhost:8080",
    secure: false
  },
  {
    context: ["/oauth2"],
    target: "http://localhost:9000",
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
  },
  {
    context: ["/login"],
    target: "http://localhost:8080",
    secure: false
  }
];

But I couldn't get a working example.
I have provided the whole code on github: https://github.com/lorenzBern/oauth-sample
Can anybody help me to get a working example?
